# Volume muting when player is hidden / shown with jQuery

Tags: wordpress, hide, volume, mediaelement.js

I've coded a script for [this web page](http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~handstan/).

That allows me to use the thumbnails on the right hand side in order to switch the 'main video'.

All appears to work fine, however if you play one video and then switch to another, and then switch BACK to the video that was originally playing, then the volume is muted when you continue watching it.

I have noticed that you can get around it by clicking the volume tool inside the player, but the average user most likely won't figure this out.

I've tried using the `setVolume()` method on something like:

```
$('#media video')
```

But FF tells me that the method doesn't exist. Could this be because I'm just trying it from within one of my other js files whereas the media player script itself is setup with Wordpress? I'm using the WP plugin you see.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Here is my .js that switches the videos if that helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // swap media
    $('#media-feed .thumb a').click(function() {
        var mediaId = $(this).prev('input').val();
        $('#media .content').each(function() {
            if($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this).fadeOut(350);
            }
        });
        $('#media-' + mediaId).delay(500).fadeIn(350);
        return false;
    });

    // swap sidebar detail
    $('#media-feed .thumb a').mouseenter(function() {
        var mediaId = $(this).prev('input').val();
        $('#media-feed .detail').each(function() {
            if($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this).slideUp(125, function() {
                    var currentDetail = $('#media-detail-' + mediaId);
                    currentDetail.slideDown(125, function() {
                    currentDetail.css('display', 'block');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also another problem I'm having is in Internet Explorer (all versions). See above, where I said about switching from one video to another, in other browsers the videos automatically pause when you click on another thumbnail. However in IE the videos continue to play. So basically, you'd have to pause the video and THEN change main video by clicking one of the thumbnails. Again, not very user friendly.

Does anyone know of a way I can get it to function like in other browsers? I can see that even IE doesn't have this problem on [this page where the Fancybox plugin is used](http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~handstan/film-making-with-young-people-and-community-groups/).

So that makes me think there must be a way to solve it in IE on the home page.

If anyone has any advice on this too that would be great!

Thanks.